# Library for working with a 4-digit 7-segment indicator SH5461AS

Tags: library, 7-segment

Good day. Tell me an excellent library for working with a 4-digit 7-segment indicator.
I am currently using `#include <fDigitsSegtPin.h>`

But it does not allow you to display letters, does not allow you to put dots in the right place.
I think it is not flexible.
I want it to be easy enough to control the indicator and have sufficient freedom to choose segments (numbers, letters, dots, dashes). I tend to use the library: "`SevenSeg` library".

Tell me a really good option for my goal, and so that, as always, this library does not slow down all the code

I am using an indicator of the form:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one  [tm1637](https://github.com/bremme/arduino-tm1637/blob/master/README.md) sounds good. I was thinking to use it next time.
**Edit 1:**
Lately posted image suggests that it is without a separate display controller chip, then this [library](https://github.com/DeanIsMe/SevSeg/blob/master/SevSeg.h) should work.
**Edit 2:**
This library specific to the SH5461AS display: [Library](https://github.com/UniQHW/SH5461AS)
Include these three libraries:

```
#include "Segment.h"
#include "Digit.h"
#include "Display.h"
```

Print needs to be in the loop:

```
void loop() {
  d.print("1.234"); // Must be looped!
}
```

For disabling decimal points:

```
#define DISABLE_DP
```

The library's Github has very good documentation too

Comment: Oh yes, but it doesn't suit me, I forgot to clarify, I have an indicator like the one in the picture in the post above

Comment: that requires a display with TM1637 IC

Comment: @Антон I put that in the answer because I can't initiate comments. Do we have any markings on it? Looks like 12-pin 0.56", like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32658212657.html)

Comment: Yes, exactly like that

Comment: I have SH5461AS

Comment: Thank you, @Антон, I updated the answer.